# ASP.NET Metatag element

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to add metatag programatically to my page in asp.net using:

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "keywords";
meta.Content = "test,test1";
this.Master.Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

but the Master.Page.Header is always NULL.

Any ideias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<head>` element of your master page must have the `runat="server"` attribute. If it doesn't, `Page.Header` will always be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HtmlHead head = this.Master.Page.Header;
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "Description";
meta.Content = "Friendly and relevant content";
head.Controls.Add(meta);
```

Comment: Can you highlight how that is really any different?

Comment: `this.Master.Page.Header` will still be null, regardless of whether or not you store it in a variable